# Approximate unit of an involutive Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I know that every C*-algebra has an approximate unit. I have two questions:  why we cannot  show that every involutive Banach algebra has an approximate unit? I need an example of an involutive Banach algebra which does not have any approximate unit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you perhaps mean *an approximate identity* rather than *approximate units*?

Comment: @TomekKania : I'm studying Takesaki's Operator theory and in this book, he shows the family of positive elements of unit ball is an approximate unit. He does not use positive functionals to prove it. Please give me a refrence that uses positive functionals for proving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest example would be a nonzero algebra with any involution and zero multiplication.

Comment: What about the rest of my question?

Comment: Well, we can't prove that every involutive Banach algebra has approximate units because there's a counterexample as indicated by Yulia.

Comment: @TomekKania : I know it, but I can not understand which quality of a C*-algebra causes that it has an approximate unit.

Comment: Ah this is related to positive functionals on a Banach ${}^*$-algebra. Positive functionals vanish on the radical of the algebra. C${}^*$-algebras have enough positive functionals to separate points and this is the reason. Just look at the proof that C${}^*$-algebras have approximate identities.